# Hive star schema query with 'SELECT *' in sub-selects

Tags: hive, hiveql

I came across a previously implement query in Hive that I am trying to grok, and was wondering if someone could explain what the advantages (or lack there of) of the query pattern used. The query structure is a star schema that sub-selects the join tables in this manner:

```
SELECT
  a.key
  a.field1
  b.field2
  c.field3
  d.field4
FROM first a
JOIN ( SELECT * FROM second ) b ON a.key = b.key
JOIN ( SELECT * from third ) c ON a.key = c.key
JOIN ( SELECT * from fourth ) d ON a.kay = d.key
SORT BY a.key DESC;
```

The thing that is perplexing me is why would you sub-select the join tables (note the `SELECT *` with no `WHERE`) rather than join directly to them. Before I go changing legacy code queries (for other reasons), I wanted to understand what might be the goals of this approach. The query was written in the time of Hive 0.10, but we are up to Hive 0.13 now. Could this be a legacy work around for something?

Comment: thats interesting a direct join would also have given similar result. I would really like to know how and why that query came into existence. I am considering bad API implementation. It could be an underlying logic to load data from multiple tables. Because this (hive) definitely is not SQL. Lets say, so the API or library could be generating query like those within it. Another explanation would be like how English is different in US and England, they may have wanted to different query definition than standard SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any advantage in subqueries with select all and with no WHERE clause. But it maybe useful if applicable to limit columns and rows in subqueries so that their datasets will fit in memory and map-only join will work. Three subqueries in your example can be pre-calculated in parallel if hive.exec.parallel=true.
Also `SORT BY a.key DESC` seems useless in this query.

Answer (score 0):

my best guess would be that it remained from the testing phase. to keep the where clauses in their own spaces. Performance wise there is no improvement.